# How to move an object in SwiftUI with animation?

Tags: object, animation, swiftui

I want to move an object on the screen, making it harder for the user to click on.

The object will appear for a few seconds and if clicked it will provide user an advantage in the game.

I wouldn't want it to appear in one spot then a second later appear on another spot. I'd love it to slide from place to another.

My example code is below:

```
struct level1: View {

@State var makeIt10xPressed = false

@State var showWin10x = false

var timeTimer : Timer {
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
    print("timer")
    self.showWin10x = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        self.showWin10x = false
       }
    }
}

func makeIt10x () {
    if makeIt10xPressed == true {
        print("10x more point")

    }
}

func win10x () {

    self.makeIt10xPressed = true
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
     self.makeIt10xPressed = false
    }

}


var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                ZStack {

Image("mine1")
          .resizable()
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1.4, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
          .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded { value in
          print("get one point")
                        })

if self.showWin10x {
                            Button(action: {
                            self.win10x()
                            }) {
                           Image("bat").resizable.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.10 , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.10)
                            }
                            }

}

}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).onAppear() {


                 _ = self.timeTimer
}
}
}
```

I want the Image("bat") to move around the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick demo how you might achieve your goal;

I randomly changed the `View`'s offset, so it is free to travel

```swift
struct DemoView: View {

    let timer = Timer.publish(
        every: 1,       // Second
        tolerance: 0.1, // Gives tolerance so that SwiftUI makes optimization
        on: .main,      // Main Thread
        in: .common     // Common Loop
    ).autoconnect()

    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .offset(offset)
        }.onReceive(timer) { (_) in
            let widthBound = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
            let heightBound = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
            let randomOffset = CGSize(
                width: CGFloat.random(in: -widthBound...widthBound),
                height: CGFloat.random(in: -heightBound...heightBound)
            )
            withAnimation {
                self.offset = randomOffset
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

You can play with the bounds to fit your needs.

Comment: Amazing, but when I implemented this to my code, unlike your demo, the object moves a few times then stops moving. How can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure the `Timer` is alive?

Comment: I thought it would stay alive because there's "in: .common". Even when I call timer in another timer that on repeat, the object doesn't move after the initial movements.